Integration of Stepwise Function with a (possible) Unknown
How can I integrate a stepwise function, when part of the equation potentially contains an unknown?
Consider the following graph. It plots (in orange) the theoretical data reading over time when $n=1$.
Plot for y when (n=1) 1
What I wish to do is to integrate this function, increasing $n$, so that I have a valid model to fit observational data to. So far, I am having real difficulty in achieving this. I would greatly appreciate any help.
My approach thus far has been as follows:

Define the three, separate, sections:

time = 1 to $t_1$, where y=c
time = t1 to t2, where the slope changes from 0 to +ve($t_1$ = 6, in the example plot), and $y=mx+c$.
time > $t_2$, where the slope changes to zero ( example: $t_2=20$, and $y=240$)


Remove part of the stepwise nature, as shown in blue. This allows me to predict the maximal value at any time point.
Apply linear regression, to calculate the slope of the line
Then integrate each distinct section separately, and combine to form the whole. If we start with $n=1$, and the rate of addition is a constant 1 every unit time period, then

From $time=t_1$ to $time=t_2$, then $y=5\chi^2 +45\chi + 150$
We can extend this equation to cover the time period $t=0$ to $t_1$ if we "correct" the differential between the solid orange and the dashed blue lines in the graph.
When $time > t_2$, we have the situation where the flow of additions equals the flow of discontinuations, so the equation becomes linear: $y=240\chi -1572$ (if my workings are correct)



Constraint:

$y$ can only ever increase or stay the same, never decrease. (Therefore, see Update 1)

However, I am completely stuck with the following:

I've not yet been able to correct the value for $y$ when $time < t_1$
Observational data shows that in some instances, the rate of discontinuations exceeds the rate of additions, and ultimately the absolute number of entities can trend towards zero. This is showing as an error in my observational modelling, which (because it is currently purely quadratic) is showing a future value of $y$ which is less than the current value (thus violating the constraint).

i.e. The rate of change is negative, trending towards $n= zero$


For a proportion of entities, $t_2$ is not being reached; i.e. the maximum value of $y$ for a single entity is less than 240 (but more than 100). In this case, $t_2$ is unknown. My approach to this situation at this point is to define $t_2$ as a fixed value, and then to see if real-world data supports the hypothesis that observed $t_2$ differs from the theoretical model, or not.
From the arguments outlined above, I have had to revise my earlier assumption that the rate of change to $n$ is linear. It obviously isn't. However, in recognising this, I now exceed my ability to comprehend high-school maths, and to derive a more accurate model -- and thus come asking for help.

The ultimate purpose of all of this is that I need to fit observed data to the theoretical curve (using R, if relevant) - and from there give an indication (as far as is possible) of:

Future projected value of $y$
Absolute value of $n$.
Rate of change of $n$ (growth or contraction)
Some sort of estimation of $t_2$ (either absolute or relative) -- if this is even possible.

Update 1
Taking into account the constraint that this is a monotonically increasing function, the actual answer to this is going to be something like a logistic function, a Gompertz curve, or similar. The real-world data shows this S-shaped curve, but is asymmetric.

Could you joint to your question an example of data (numerical not graphical). Is this paper ansewers to your question ? https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf Pages 17-19.

Thank you. I will study this - it may indeed help. But I have no data - I wish to create a theoretical model which I can adapt to any circumstance. The example used 4 parameters:  100, 6, 10, 20 (with 20 being my potential unknown, which in practice could be lower). From this I managed to derive a quadratic, assuming a constant growth rate. This assumption has since been shown to be incorrect. My alternative approach is looking at real data, although this is not helpful at the beginning. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656971/curve-fitting-and-parameter-derivation

For a model valid in any circumstance the limitation to picewise linear function is certainly not a good idea.
